# Proper usage of "callable default function" in Django REST Framework (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

#### Question:

How can I access the ***serializer instance*** or ***any relevant arguments*** in the **default callable function** of DRF field?

---

#### Scenario:

I have a serializer configuration as below,

```
def bar_value_callable_function(serializer_instance):
    if serializer_instance.context['request'].method == 'GET':
        return 'return value One'
    return 'return value Two'
```

class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bar = serializers.CharField(**source='foo.bar', default=bar_value_callable_function**)
and when I try to serialize the data as,

```
serializer = FooSerializer(foo_instance, context={'request': request})
print(serializer.data)
```

I am gettting error as,

```
TypeError: bar_value_callable_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'serializer_instance'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**
For DRF>=3.12, use this king of default class

```
class DefaultBarValue:
    requires_context = True

    def __call__(self, serializer_instance):
        if serializer_instance.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            return 'return value One'
        return 'return value Two'
```

---

pass a ***class instance*** instead of *function* to the **`default`** argument

```
# default callable class
class DefaultBarValue:
    """
    "Method `set_context` on defaults is deprecated and will
    no longer be called starting with 3.12. Instead set
    `requires_context = True` on the class, and accept the
    context as an additional argument.
    """
    requires_context = True  # for DRF>=3.12
    serializer_instance = None # not required for DRF>=3.12

    def set_context(self, serializer_instance): # not required for DRF>=3.12
        self.serializer_instance = serializer_instance

    def __call__(self, serializer_instance=None):
        if serializer_instance is None:  # will be None for older versions of DRF
            if self.serializer_instance.context['request'].method == 'GET':
                return 'return value One'
            return 'return value Two'
        else:  # for DRF>=3.12
            if serializer_instance.context['request'].method == 'GET':
                return 'return value One'
            return 'return value Two'
```

```
# serializer
class FooSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bar = serializers.CharField(source='foo.bar', default=DefaultBarValue())
```

Comment: It's frustrating that the official documentation says to use `requires_context` when the 3.12 release isn't even out yet. Thanks for making this Q&A.

Comment: In the `__call__` method, it should be `if serializer_instance is None:`
(for older version of drf)